# 16.04: I can no longer open time and date settings

Tags: settings, time, date

I can click on the time and date settings from the drop-down menu in the top right all I want, but nothing happens. I've tried rebooting. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Ubuntu release/version?

Comment: @MichaelBay - the subject start with 16.04 - seems to be the version

Comment: @Yaron Yes, but all other details matters for the case, particularly the desktop environment because each uses different software.

Comment: It's 16.04.3, desktop environment is Unity.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the situation where when I click on date and time settings, date and time settings pops up instead of doing nothing.